# How do I use a Derby database?

Tags: mysql, database, derby

I am using an application that has an embedded Derby database. It is possible to switch the application to use MySQL but they recommended sticking with the default which is the Derby database, so I did.

I have searched online for more information on this database having never heard of it but haven't come across a lot of details.

How can I run queries etc. against a Derby database, as I can with MySQL (using `MySQL`), Oracle (using `sqlplus`) etc.

Is there a similar sort of way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Derby's "ij" tool for interactive queries, or you can use a JDBC-aware database tool such as [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or NetBeans or Eclipse.

Here is the Derby documentation: http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html

Specifically for using ij, read this: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tools/ctoolsij34525.html

Note that since the application is using Derby as an embedded database, Derby won't let you run interactive queries against the database while the application has it open; only one application at a time can open an embedded database. You'll have to shut the application down first, then use ij or Squirrel to access the database tables.

Answer (score 1):

ij is an interactive SQL scripting tool that comes with Derby. Please [ref. this](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ij_intro.html) and [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/ij.html).

Comment: Including a bit more content of your references would improve the quality of your answer. I fear it will go into the low quality queue else.

Comment: What's wrong with that answer? "ij" is the interactive query tool that comes with Derby; it is used with Derby just as you would use sqlplus with Oracle. Here's some additional ij docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tools/ctoolsij34525.html